# Grab objects level below w JOLT

Tags: json, jolt

From REST API I receive next JSON:

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "content": {
      "icon_256x256": {
        "flags": [],
        "id": 26864619,
        "type": "static"
      },
      "image_1080x607": {
        "flags": [],
        "id": 26864707,
        "type": "static"
      }
    },
    "status": "blocked",
    "textblocks": {
      "cta_sites_full": {
        "text": "learnMore",
        "title": ""
      },
      "text_220": {
        "text": "Domain",
        "title": ""
      },
      "text_90": {
        "text": "Don't worry, be happy!",
        "title": "Test!"
      }
    },
    "urls": {
      "primary": {
        "id": 90970124,
        "preview_link": "",
        "url_types": [
          "external_new",
          "external"
        ]
      },
      "url_slide_1": {
        "id": 90970124,
        "preview_link": "",
        "url_object_type": "domain"
      }
    },
    "user_can_request_remoderation": false
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "content": {
      "icon_256x256": {
        "flags": [],
        "id": 268,
        "type": "static"
      },
      "image_1080x607": {
        "flags": [],
        "id": 2686,
        "type": "static"
      }
    },
    "status": "blocked",
    "textblocks": {
      "cta_sites_full": {
        "text": "learnMore",
        "title": ""
      },
      "text_220": {
        "text": "Domain",
        "title": ""
      },
      "text_90": {
        "text": "ANOTHER TEXT",
        "title": "Test!"
      }
    },
    "urls": {
      "primary": {
        "id": 90970124,
        "preview_link": "",
        "url_types": [
          "external_new",
          "external"
        ]
      },
      "url_slide_1": {
        "id": 90970124,
        "preview_link": "",
        "url_object_type": "domain"
      }
    },
    "user_can_request_remoderation": false
  }
]
```

I want to grab from `content` objects 1 level below: in this case it's `icon_256x256` and `image_1080x607` and grab field `id` and stay it like it was, but only need `id` field. Also I need field `textblocks` and inside `urls` do the same like with `content`. So I expect to get this result:

```json
[
   {
      "content":{
         "icon_256x256":{
            "id":26864619
         },
         "image_1080x607":{
            "id":26864707
         }
      },
      "status":"blocked",
      "textblocks":{
         "cta_sites_full":{
            "text":"learnMore",
            "title":""
         },
         "text_220":{
            "text":"Domain",
            "title":""
         },
         "text_90":{
            "text":"Don't worry, be happy!",
            "title":"Test!"
         }
      },
      "urls":{
         "primary":{
            "id":90970124
         },
         "url_slide_1":{
            "id":90970124
         }
      }
   },
   {
      "content":{
         "icon_256x256":{
            "id":268
         },
         "image_1080x607":{
            "id":2686
         }
      },
      "status":"blocked",
      "textblocks":{
         "cta_sites_full":{
            "text":"learnMore",
            "title":""
         },
         "text_220":{
            "text":"Domain",
            "title":""
         },
         "text_90":{
            "text":"Don't worry, be happy!",
            "title":"Test!"
         }
      },
      "urls":{
         "primary":{
            "id":90970124
         },
         "url_slide_1":{
            "id":90970124
         }
      }
   }
]
```

Objects inside `content` may have different names, like `video_landscape` instead of `icon_256x256`, so I can't loop based on names. But it always 1 level below, as you can see. Same for `urls` field. I hope I describe it clear!

My attempt was, but it doesn't work(:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "content": {
        "*": {
          "id": "content.&1.id"
        }
      },
      "textblocks": {
        "@": "textblocks.&"
      },
      "urls": {
        "primary": {
          "id": "urls.primary.id"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following **shift** transformation spec :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "content|urls": {
          "*": {
            "id": "&2.&1.id" // &2 represents going 2 levels up in order to grab
                             // the keys content and urls
                             // and &1 stands for getting the respective subkeys 
                             // of them from just one level up
          }
        },
        "status|textblocks": "&" // replicate the values of these attributes respectively
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**Edit** ( based on your comment : "*What if inside JSON there will be multiple objects? With same structure (id, content, etc).*" ) :

Then use the following one, having not seen the new desired output, thinking that you have probably want to have an array of objects rather than some leaf node arrays which are generated in this case :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "content|urls": {
          "*": {
            "id": "[&3].&2.&1.&"
          }
        },
        "status|textblocks": "[&1].&"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks again! It works great, but now I faced some issue. What if inside JSON there will be multiple objects? With same structure (id, content, etc).

Comment: I updated question (don't want to create new). I tried to remove  `*` after `content|urls`, but invalid result. Maybe I understood you wrong

Comment: Hi @MarkAvreliy , I have added the case, take care.